# Velocity and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, velocity

I have a bit of a problem here:

```
#foreach($image in $command.lessonLearned.images)

      Image: $image.fileName <input type="submit" onclick="submitForm();setImageToRemove($image.id);setAction('removeImage');" value="REMOVE"/><br/> 
#end
```

$image.id inside the onclick event is not evaluated as a velocity variable. How do I make it write out the variable content and not just the variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that $image.id has a value?  Was it $image.ID or $image.getID() that you should have typed?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `$image.id` with `${image.id}`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, actually, you were right, Nathan...we found that the problem was a type-o... How typical.

Thanks for your answers, anyway (: